# Do not allow packets of the same size consecutively? iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, debian-jessie

Is it possible to block packets of the same size consecutively?
Example: A 32 size packet is received, not receiving more size 32 packets until another size pack is received.

How could he do it? I was thinking about the recent module but I'm not sure how the rule would be.

Answer (score 0):

I never tied or  used this kind of request trough network, but you can try:

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 --match length --length 32 -j DROP

Please update us on result. Hope it helps.

Comment: That would only (and always) block size 32 packets. OP only wants to block them until a size != 32 is received, say a size 27 packet, then block size 27 until a size != 27 comes in, then switch to blocking that size, etc.

Comment: Yes youre right! Than this is hard scripting.
Or try same article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/955425/allow-x-packets-per-second-with-same-data-length-iptables